# r: repeat each value and add a additional string

Tags: r

I need following:
repeat two values, each 3 times: I can do it with

```
rplcts = rep(c("Trt","Ctl"), each=3)
```

but I also want to add to each string in one group following values: 1,2,3
so, at the end I need this:

```
"Ctl1" "Ctl2" "Ctl3" "Trt1" "Trt2" "Trt3"
```

Is there a smart way to do it in r?

Comment: `paste0(rep(c("Trt","Ctl"), each=3), c(1, 2, 3))`?

Comment: `paste0(rplcts, 1:3)`

Answer (score 1):

You essentially only  need to paste two vectors.

```
paste0(rep(c("Trt", "Ctl"), each = 3), 
       rep(1:3, 2))
```

A more general solution could be

```
mySeq <- function(groups, each){
  paste0(rep(groups, each=each),
         1:each) # Element recycling will match the length
}

mySeq(c("Trt", "Ctl"), 3)
```

Comment: Due to element-recycling, you could omit the second call to rep.

Comment: I often avoid taking advantage of recycling because I'm terrified of what happens when the one vector's length isn't a multiple of the other's length.  But in the controlled state of that function, I think it works nicely.  Good catch.

Comment: I agree with you (better safe than sorry), but in this very controlled case it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is is with handy magrittr syntax:

```
library(magrittr)

c("Trt", "Ctl") %>%
  rep(each = 3) %>%
  paste0(c(1, 2, 3))
```